# Send UTF-8 encoded mail with Email::Sender

Tags: perl, email, utf-8

I'm trying to send an mail with Email::Sender which contains umlauts.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Email::Sender::Simple qw(sendmail);
use Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP::TLS;
use Email::Simple ();
use Email::Simple::Creator ();

open(my $mailbody, "<", "mail-content");

my $smtpserver = 'smtp.gmail.com';
my $smtpport = 587;
my $smtpuser   = 'example@mail.de';
my $smtppassword = 'password';

my $transport = Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP::TLS->new({
  host => $smtpserver,
  port => $smtpport,
  username => $smtpuser,
  password => $smtppassword,
});

my $email = Email::Simple->create(
  header => [
    To      => 'example@mail.de',
    From    => 'example@mail.de',
    Subject => 'Mail',
  ],
  body => <$mailbody>,
);

sendmail($email, { transport => $transport });
```

The received mail looks like `gegrÃŒÃt` instead of `gegrüßt`.
Is there any way i can specify how the mail is getting encoded in perl?

Answer (score 3):

You have

```
open(my $mailbody, "<", "mail-content");
```

If the file `mail-content` contains UTF-8 encoded data, you must open it with the appropriate IO layer:

```
open my $mailbody, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', 'mail-content'
    or croak ...;
```

If, in addition, the source code of your script contains UTF-8 strings that will be incorporated in the message, you must have `use utf8;` in your script.

In addition, if any header fields include UTF-8 encoded strings, you must [encode those strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11970433/100754) as well.

Comment: Well, create a simple `'mail-content'` file, and paste the hexdump in your question then. Is the file really UTF-8 encoded?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Add a `Content-Type` line to your message:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

You may also need to specify your input encoding when reading the mail file:

```
open ( my $input, "<:encoding(UTF-8)", "Your_File" ) or die $!;
```

Comment: Adding both lines changes nothing at all. I just noticed that the mail is shown correctly at outlook.com but not in the preview on my iPhone

Comment: Maybe Microsoft and iPhone don't go well together. ;)

Comment: @ProfGhost on a more serious note: did you add the `Content-Type` header correctly in the params of the `E::S->create` or did you put it in front of the mail body? The latter would not work.

Comment: @simbabque  put it in the mail body, i will try it in the create.

Comment: Add FULL set of MIME headers. 
`MIME-Version: 1.0`
`Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8`
`Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit`

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem and could solve it by adding a

```
require Net::SMTP;
```

before using Email::Simple. This seems to be related to a 'workaround' in `Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP` where it says

```
utf8::downgrade($next_hunk) if (Net::SMTP->VERSION || 0) < 3.07;
```

If `Net::SMTP` is not loaded this resolves to `if (0 < 3.07)` and causes the downgrade.